# Why can't I insert data into my database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

I want to do a very simple `INSERT INTO` operation, but nothing happens. I see no errors and also I see no changes in the database.

I suspect my connection string is wrong, but how can I know that? If so how can I fix it? (local host)

```
protected void RegButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Bodin\\Desktop\\FullFart\\App_Data\\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
   string sql = "INSERT INTO student (navn, etternavn)  " + "VALUES('" + NavnTextBox.Text + "', '" + EtterNavnTextBox.Text + "');";
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);

   try
   {
      conn.Open();
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
   }
   finally
   {
      conn.Close();
   }        
}
```

Any ideas why the above code does nothing? (It should add new rows every time executed)

**Update**

Related to SQL injection. This is a demo program for some homework, that is why i don't use parameters. It is my friends laptop and i only have installed Visual studion 2008 and SQL server 2005. I don't have any other gadgets I can manually add values to the database from visual studio, so that means the DB works. But how can i correctly configure the connection String?

Comment: Run a trace with SQL Server Profiler so you can see if the query executes at all.

Comment: Sorry i am very new to .NET i only have Visual Studio 2008. Where can i have the option there to execute that query?

Comment: You should also use parameters to avoid sql injection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: @sfrj - SQL Server Profiler is a part of SQL Server, you should find it in start menu under SQL Server -> Performance Tools. An example how to use it: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO3965&key=55263&actp=LIST

Comment: @_simon_: SQL Server Profiler is not part of SQL Server **Express** if I'm not mistaken (which is what sfrj seems to be using when looking at the connection string)

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns number of affected records. What number returns it in your case?

Comment: Is the database created? Creating user instances must be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True;User Instance=yes");    
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into pro_details values('" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "')", con);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Use Connection string in this way

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\WebSites\\WebSitelab\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Please check your connection string

```
string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Bodin\\Desktop\\FullFart\\App_Data\\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Comment: its not good to write a insert statement like that , it can lead to sql injection and someone can get your database down with in few minutes...

Comment: I never use these statements i always love to work in 3 tier architecture and pass the parameters to method and will fire a command. As he is very new in VS so i have suggested to use in this way. Atleast he'll start to learn whats the problems going ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why your connection string would be wrong - I personally don't like the "AttachDbFile" approach. Also: you should a) avoid concatenating together your SQL command strings (because of SQL injection attacks), and b) you should put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects into using blocks to avoid memory issues.

My recommendation would be: fire up SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express and **attach** that database to your SQL Server Express server - then use something like this:

```
string connString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Student(navn, etternavn) " + 
   "VALUES(@navn, @etternvan)";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
   // set up parameters
   myCmd.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = NavnTextBox.Text.Trim();
   myCmd.Parameters.Add("@etternavn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = EtterNavnTextBox.Text.Trim();

   try
   {
       conn.Open();
       myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
   }
}
```

The SQL query as such is looking OK from my point of view - it should work just fine.

The problem with the `AttachDbFile=` and `UserInstance=true` is (amongst other things) that they often initialize a database from scratch, each time your app runs. It's absolutely possible your insert really actually worked, but next time you run your app, it's being initialized back to a default state again and makes you believe it's not done anything.....

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late here but I was facing this problem now and found a solution. I want to share it so that if anybody comes here to seek some help on this matter....

So what I did was as written:

> You can leave the data file outside the project and create a
>   connection to it in Database Explorer. When the IDE asks you to bring
>   the file into the project, just say no. This way, both the design-time
>   and the run-time will be using the same data file but the downside is
>   that the path in the connection string will be hard coded and
>   therefore it’ll be harder to share the project and deploy the app.
>   Before deploying the app, just make sure to replace the full path in
>   the settings with a relative path.

You can see it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your code in some company, don't code as below , it can lead to SQL Injection.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO student (navn, etternavn)  " + "VALUES('" + NavnTextBox.Text + "', '" + EtterNavnTextBox.Text + "');";
```

change to...

```
nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@MyName, @MyNumber)";
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
```

coming to why it's not workig, you can easily find out by breaking into visual Studio, use debugging options. Use Ctrl + Alt + E and say break on exceptions and select checkBox runtime errors, it can tell you what the error is.

other wise , paste your sql directly i sequel server ad give a try